# Getting malformed SOAP response

Tags: c#, java, android, xml, soap

I'm new to Web Services and I'm writting an Android application that can communicate with the web service. But when I try to show the results in the android screen, it's showing:

```
MethodNameResponse{MethodNameResult=anyType{};}
```

The Web service is supposed to do a simple query on the servers database and post results, here is the code of the method calling the web service:

```
public void Convert(String val) {
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

            PropertyInfo p = new PropertyInfo();
            p.setName(PROPERTY_NAME);
            p.setValue(val);
            p.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(p);



            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE ahs = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            ahs.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                     TextView.setText(response.toString());



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
}
```

My guess is that either there is something wrong with the service, or I'm interpreting the data incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace envelope.body in with envelope.get response()

Your response in a SoapObject - so not just something you can necessarily toString. Assuming you know what the response from the service looks like you will need to map the data from the response. (For example, your response maybe a complex XML structure, so the SoapObject response will reflect that).

Here is a pretty complete example of using the SoapObject and mapping the response

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html